# Co-ordinate Geometry(Incenter)

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Is there any way of finding the incenter of a triangle, when the equation of all three lines of the triangle are given, without finding out the vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving $$
     \frac{a_{1} X+b_{1}Y+c_{1}}{\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+b_{1}^{2}}}
=\pm \frac{a_{2} X+b_{2}Y+c_{2}}{\sqrt{a_{2}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}}}
=\pm \frac{a_{3} X+b_{3}Y+c_{3}}{\sqrt{a_{3}^{2}+b_{3}^{2}}}
$$

gives one in-centre and three ex-centres.